# trying to reconnect error while upgrading muk_dms module from odoo12 to 14

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13, odoo-14

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/akhil/Downloads/odoo14/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception

```
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
```

File "/home/akhil/Downloads/odoo14/odoo-14.0/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception

```
raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
```

TypeError: **call**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'su'

while I upgrading the module muk_dms from version 12 to version 14 ,
trying to reconnect error is showing in localhost and found the error in the image

Comment: Can you please remove the picture and paste the error as text?

Comment: i have edited, please have a lokk

Comment: Are you sure `muk_dms` is out for Odoo 14 yet? I don't see a branch on [their github](https://github.com/muk-it/muk_dms).

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Than you either have to wait for that version or have to migrate it yourself. Alternatively you can try to user 13.0, because that version is there.

Comment: i am trying to migrate it myself

Comment: can you please create  create a chat room if possible, i have some doubts regarding the migration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231740/discussion-between-akhil-alexander-and-czoellner).

Comment: I don't have time for that, sorry.